# VBA not refreshing calculated cells & links

Tags: excel, vba

In Short: My update macro runs, but cells are not updated if additional SUBs are included. Cells are updated if no additional SUBs are included.

I have a series of spreadsheets with anywhere between 5000 and 25000 calculated cells. My end goal is to link these spreadsheets together to iteratively update all cells and links.
The update code by itself works fine. But cell values no longer update if I include a timing loop or a check to see of all values are updated.

The basic code that works:

```
     Sub Global()
      Dim ActiveWKB As Workbook
      Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      Application.Calculation = xlManual
      Set ActiveWKB = Workbooks.Open("Master.xlsx")
      Set ActiveWKB = Workbooks.Open("Sub01.xlsx")
      Sub_Update
    End Sub
    Sub Sub_Update()
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
      Application.CalculateFull
      ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources
    End Sub
```

I am adding the following code (the code itself runs fine), but does NOT update the calculated links & cells:

I've added the following to Sub Global, below Sub_Update:

```
     Sub_Pause (45)
```

Sub_Pause contains the following code:

```
      Dim StartTime
      Dim Delay
      StartTime = Timer
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
          Do
          Delay = Timer - StartTime
          Application.ScreenUpdating = True
          DoEvents
      Loop Until Delay >= EndPoint
      ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll   
      Application.Calculation = xlManual
      MsgBox(“Sub_Pause Done”)
     End Sub
```

This SUB pauses for 45 seconds, displays the message "Sub_Pause Done", then the macro ends.

After running WITHOUT Sub_Pause, my dashboard shows how many cells remain to be updated, (initially at 10134) and counts down to zero. The cells themselves slowly change from #N/A to the updated value.

After running WITH Sub_Pause, my dashboard shows the initial number of cells to be updated (10134) and the cell values are never refreshed (Display #N/A instead)

I've tried replacing the timer in Sub_Pause with the following partial code to simply count the number of #NA's remaining:

```
      NAs = Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(Range(“C2:Q1500),“#N/A”)
```

I embedded a message box within the Do Until loop to display the variable NAs.

Stepping through shows the variable NAs never changes from the initial count of 10134.

Any suggestions on how I can get the values to update while running Sub_Pause?

The purpose of this sub is to pause the macro long enough for all cells to update before I save and close the file, then open up the next spreadsheet file.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

**Update:**
After the macro ended I accidentally hit a hotkey to turn on automatic calculation (Automatic calculation was already on).

All cells immediately updated to their calculated values and my dashboard updated the number of #NA values from 10134 to 0.

Thinking this may have been a screen refresh problem I inserted the following code into my Sub_Pause:

```
    Dim NACount As Long
.
 .
  .
        NACount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C2:Q1100"), "#N/A")
        MsgBox (NACount)
```

The full Sub_Pause reads:

```
    Sub Sub_Pause(EndPoint As Long)

    Dim StartTime
    Dim Delay
    StartTime = Timer
    Dim NACount As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Do
        Delay = Timer - StartTime
        DoEvents
        ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
        NACount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C2:Q1100"), "#N/A")
        MsgBox (NACount)

    Loop Until Delay >= EndPoint

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    NACount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C2:Q1100"), "#N/A")
    MsgBox (NACount)

    End Sub
```

Both within the Do Until loop and at the end of Sub_Pause the NACount came back as 10134, showing this is not a screen refresh problem, but the macro code is not recognizing that the cells have been updated.
As soon as the macro finished I immediately hit the hotkey to turn automatic calculations "On" (they were already on).

The count of #NAs immediately set to zero.

If there were simply a screen refresh issue, the NACount would reflect the internal value of zero. Because it reflects the internal count of 10134, I have to believe that the VBA code is not recognizing that the cell values have been updated.

I ran these on my laptop as well (from OneDrive) with the same results.

Any insights? Suggestions?

Comment: `xlCalculationAutomatic` though I think it's the same value as `xlAutomatic`

Comment: Where did you insert `Sub_Pause (45)` inside `Global` ?

Comment: @Tim: xlCalculationAutomatic has the same outcome as xlAutomatic. Thanks though.

Comment: @DecimalTurn: The Sub_Pause is placed immediately below Sub_Update

Comment: Is it necessary to include `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll` inside `Sub_Pause`? According to the [MDSN Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.refreshall), it "refreshes all external data ranges" which seems like it would restart the whole updating process.

Comment: Actually, I just made a test and apparently `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll` does not refresh external data links, so you can ignore my comment.

Comment: @DecimalTurn: Thanks for your efforts. I had previously removed all RefreshAll commands as well, but still didn't work.  At this point I'd be happy to know if anyone can duplicate my problem (so I know I'm not completely crazy), or if there is an alternate solution that does work.

Comment: @DecimalTurn: It has been a few months, but I wanted to tell you the proper command for refreshing external data links: `Application.CalculateFullRebuild`. This commnd forces Excel to rebuild each formula and reconnect to external links, refreshing the external data. This, coupled with your timing solution provides the flexibility I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. There is weirdly no mention of it on this [MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/excel-recalculation?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to replicate those kinds of problems with cells and calculations refreshing since there is a lot going on when those happen and some other factors can interfere which makes things more uncertain.

In order to have a more reliable method to create a pause in your code, I would suggest using the `Application.OnTime` method. It will schedule a macro at a later time, so you can return the full control to Excel in the meantime in order to let Excel update calculations and cells.

For example, you could do the following:

```
Public RepeatCounter As Long

Sub Main()

    Dim ActiveWKB As Workbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Set ActiveWKB = Workbooks.Open("Master.xlsx")
    Set ActiveWKB = Workbooks.Open("Sub01.xlsx")
    Sub_Update


    RepeatCounter = 0 'Reset Counter
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "PauseInOrOut" 'Start Pause
End Sub


Sub PauseInOrOut()

    'Customizable parameter
    Const RepeatLimit As Long = 3

    If RepeatCounter < RepeatLimit Then
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C2:Q1100"), "#N/A") = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Pause completed"
            'You can call the code that needs to run after the pause here
        Else
            RepeatCounter = RepeatCounter + 1
            Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "PauseInOrOut" 'Run this macro again
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Values couldn't be updated within time limit."
    End If

End Sub
```

Here, I've put a waiting time of 10 seconds before running your "pause" macro the next time. I've also added a limit, so it wouldn't run forever. Feel free to modify the condition for the pause to be completed in a way that suits your needs, I've added an example here that would match what I got from your question regarding the NAs.

Comment: This approach solved the update problem.  THANK YOU.

Comment: Sorry that my reputation points don't meet the minimum for my vote to count. I did vote this as the most useful.

Comment: @Steve I'm glad I could help. If this solves your question, you can still accept it by [clicking the check mark beside it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/372533). This does not require reputation.